# navbar container to mobile collapse full width(container-fluid)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have a container div where i have my logo, and at the right i have my menu, what i want to do is, when the navbar gets at screen size mobile i want each

to be on a row and each row is the size of a container-fluid, at the moment the issue is that each li size is the same of my container, how i can change this?

this is my code:

```
    <div id="navigation_bar">
        <div class="content">
            <div id="logo">
                <a href="index.html">
                    <img class="logo_dark" src="images/virtuai/logo-dark.png" alt="Enar Logo">
                    <img class="logo_light" src="images/logo-light.png" alt="Enar Logo">
                </a>
            </div>
            <nav id="main_nav navbar-right">
                <div id="nav_menu">
                    <span class="mobile_menu_trigger">
                            <a href="#" class="nav_trigger"><span></span></a>
                    </span>
                    <ul id="navy" class="clearfix" style="float:right">
                        <li class="normal_menu mobile_menu_toggle current_page_item">
                            <a href="index.html"><span>HOME</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="normal_menu mobile_menu_toggle current_page_item">
                            <a href="index.html"><span>ABOUT US</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="normal_menu mobile_menu_toggle current_page_item">
                            <a href="index.html"><span>SOLUTIONS</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="normal_menu mobile_menu_toggle current_page_item">
                            <a href="index.html"><span>CONTACT US</span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <!-- End Nav -->
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code..**
  overwrite the bootstrap container width

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  body .container{
    width:100% !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: add one more parent class to the css. otherwise bootstrap will overwrite your class.

Comment: well i tried, i think something is wrong with my css :S, can i share the git with you? :S